# Is it possible to specify multiple gravity values in spinner item custom_style.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, gravity

I have textview.xml, which is the item style for spinners.

```
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
  android:textSize="18sp">
</TextView>
```

I know that it is possible to specify both `(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)`, but in xml that doesn't work - text is moved to the left only.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can specify a horizontal gravity and a vertical gravity that way but two horizontal settings does not make sense.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. It was actually "left|center_vertical" of course. Now it works, thanks, for pointing out.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

87element,

I believe you intended to use `layout_gravity` you are only using `gravity`??

Yes, you can combined two of these `layout_gravity` attributes together with the '|' as mentioned in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_gravity

But even using `layout_gravity` instead of just `gravity` (as adamp stated in his comment), the settings you are trying to combine don't make sense.  You are telling it basically to align left and center along the same row.  Both `left` and `center_horizontal` in this case refer to horizontal positions.

Where are you trying to align the `TextView` relative to the parent?

Your parent layout is like a grid where you can select a position:

|[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]|

|[ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ]|

|[ 7 ] [ 8 ] [ 9 ]|

1. Top-Left: `android:layout_gravity="top|left"`
2. Top-Center: `android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"`
3. Top-Right: `android:layout_gravity="top|right"`
4. Center-Left: `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"`
5. Very Center: `android:layout_gravity="center"`
6. Center-Right: `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"`
7. Bottom-Left: `android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"`
8. Bottom-Center: `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`
9. Bottom-Right: `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the "map" helped greatly! Nevertheless, I should mention, that I was intended to use exactly `android:gravity` attribute. My `TextView` goes as item layout parameter for `ArrayAdapter` of my spinner; `android:layout_gravity` didn't do any changes. Was close to solution, except for this silly positioning mistake, you and adamp pointed me out. Thanks again!

Comment: what is the meaning of: ` android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|end"
`is there an contrudiction among the values?

Answer (score 25):

Just in case anyone else was as stupid as me. Don't forget to remove spaces.
`android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"`
but `android:gravity="center_horizontal | bottom"` isn't valid.